# Combine 2 Tables on 2 columns but different value columns - MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having difficulties merging 2 tables, which each have a different value column and 2 columns that are identical.

Table1 has the columns; Proj, Mnth, Left

Table2 has the columns; Project, Mnth, Total

I'm trying to achieve a table that has four columns; Project, Mnth, Left, Total. And aggregates the sums of Left and Total, and groups by project and Mnth so each row is unique with respect to Project and Mnth.

```
SELECT Proj AS Project, Mnth, Left 
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Project, Mnth, Total
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Project, Mnth;
```

This is what I've tried so far, but with no effect.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Updated with MS Access tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try assigning a 0 value to the missing columns in table 1 and table 2, and do the sum aggregation after the union.

Also in some databases left is a reserved word so you may need to use quotes to avoid syntax errors.

```
select  Project , Mnth , sum("left") as Left , sum(Total) as Total
from 
(
    SELECT Proj AS Project, Mnth, a."left" , 0 as Total FROM Table1 a
        UNION ALL
    SELECT Project, Mnth, 0 as Left, Total FROM Table2 b
) t
GROUP BY Project, Mnth;
```